# Passing a template func. as a func. ptr to an overloaded func. - is there a way to compile this code?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Just a general c++ curiosity:

This code below shouldn't compile because it's impossible to know which to instantiate:  **temp(const int&) or temp(const string&)**  when calling func(temp) - this part i know.

What i would like to know is if there is anything i can do to the line marked **PASSINGLINE** to get the compiler to deduce that i want **FPTR1** called and not **FPTR2** ?

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

/*FPTR1*/ void func(void(*fptr)(const int&)){ fptr(1001001);} 

/*FPTR2*/ void func(void(*fptr)(const string&)){ fptr("1001001"); } 

template <typename T>
void temp(const T &t){  cout << t << endl; }

int main(){
    /*PASSINGLINE*/ func(temp); 
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func(temp<int>);
```

There's no way to make the compiler infer the template argument, that is more succinct or clearer than just explicitly specifying it, in this case.

Edit: The following code compiles without warning and produces the expected result:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

/*FPTR1*/ void func(void(*fptr)(const int&)){ fptr(1001001);}

/*FPTR2*/ void func(void(*fptr)(const string&)){ fptr("1001001"); }

template <typename T>
void temp(const T &t){  cout << t << endl; }

int main(){
    /*PASSINGLINE*/ func(temp<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Loud: I guess you are confused by errors in your question's code.  The answer works fine on GCC 4.x.

Comment: @LoudNPossiblyRight: Works perfectly well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `static_cast`:

```
func (static_cast <void(*)(const int&)> (&temp));
```

Tested with GCC 4.x.

Comment: @Loud can you please elaborate? It looks valid to me.